# Orchard 1.7 - Create custom Workflow Activity for Unpublished

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I needed to tap into a list of activities in Orchard CMS; unpublished activity being one of the requirements. I have looked and found out that Orchard default Workflow activity list doesn't have a unpublished activity.

I have built a module that add my own custom Workflow Activities. I have had no problem creating activities and making them work but I have no idea how to bind one of these with an event. Even if I copy the publish activity that is found in the default activity folder of Workflow module, the copied activity doesn't get bind to any event.

How can I make it so that my activity class is called whenever someone unpublishes or drafts a post.

I have also created a thread [here](https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/536986) but so far no answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I couldn't find much help on Orchard CMS and ended up finding a solution myself. It took me a lot of time to get this done though.

First thing I found was that `Orchard.Workflows.Activities` has a file `ContentActivity`. In this file there are other classes that inherits the `ContentActivity` class `ContentCreatedActivity`, `ContentUpdatedActivity` and `ContentPublishedActivity`. All these classes are activities that subscribe to `ContentActivity` that is an event activity. They subscribe to the Create, Update and Publish events of the Orchard core.

If you look into `Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.ContentHandler` you'd see the list of default events provided by Orchard CMS core.

I was interested in the `OnUnpublished` event, so in my module I created a handler that would listen to that event.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Orchard.ContentManagement;
using Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers;
using Orchard.Workflows.Services;

namespace MyModule.Handlers {
    public class WorkflowContentHandler : ContentHandler {
        public WorkflowContentHandler(IWorkflowManager workflowManager) {
            OnUnpublished<ContentPart>(
                (context, part) =>
                    workflowManager.TriggerEvent("ContentUnpublished",
                    context.ContentItem,
                    () => new Dictionary<string, object> { { 
                              "Content", context.ContentItem } }));
        }
    }
}
```

After which we create our custom workflow activity for Unpublished. This class inherits from `ContentActivity` like its siblings, so it can start workflow and would be an event.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Orchard.Localization;
using Orchard.Workflows.Models;
using Orchard.Workflows.Services;
using Orchard.Workflows.Activities;

namespace MyModule.WorkFlow
{
    public class ContentUnpublishedActivity : ContentActivity
    {
        public override string Name
        {
            get { return "ContentUnpublished"; }
        }

        public override LocalizedString Description
        {
            get { return T("Content is Unpublished."); }
        }
    }
}
```

And that's it. Once you've done this the new `Content Unpublished` activity would show up in the Workflow activity list. You can use it in conjunction to other Activities to execute your own workflow after any content has been unpublished.

[image: Content Unpublished Activity in Workflow list]

I can't believe it was this easy. Took me 3 days to figure it out and I was pulling my hair that I don't have much of to start with. 
The lack of support and resources for Orchard CMS really annoys me sometime. I hope this would help save some time for anyone who has run into similar problems.

Comment: We really really need a better documentation for Orchard.

Comment: The documentation project takes contributions. This answer would be a great addition, for example.