# Scheduled un-publish in OrchardCMS?

Tags: orchardcms

How would I automatically un-publish a content item according to a schedule in Orchard CMS? I'm guessing this would be a scheduled task, but I'm not sure where to begin.

Comment: Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22242754/orchard-1-7-create-custom-workflow-activity-for-unpublished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the 'Archive Later' part (enable the 'Archive Later' module), add it on the content definition of your content type.